# UIStackvView jumping in the UIScrollView. Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I understand that this is most likely a matter of limitations. But when I set the width to the view it still doesn't help me.
I find similar questions. But they don't solve my problem.

[How to get rid of this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4avN.gif)

```swift
lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    return scrollView
}()
```

```swift
private func setupScrollViewConstraint() {
    let frameLayoutGuide = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        frameLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        frameLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        frameLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor)
    ])
}
```

```swift
private func setupStackViewConstraint() {
    let contentLayoutGuide = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide       
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)])
}
```

Comment: But if you can't scroll horizontally, wouldn't the scrollview's contents get cut off?

Comment: @aheze I wish there was no way to do it like in GIF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to fix in the center the stack that is in the scroll view.

```
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
```